# Upgrade to Cloud Tools For Eclipse 1.4.0 appengine-api now missing

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse

I upgraded the Google Cloud tools to version 1.4.0 and now my projects do not have the appengine-api jar file. (Maybe others) Now I can a memcacheservice exception.

How do I get the appengine api jar back into the build path? Any help or advice would be great. Thanks.

These are the release notes. https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/release-notes

```
com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheServiceException

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheServiceException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:354)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
```

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the Cloud Tools people on github and they got me a workaround.

You have to take their appengine-api jar from their location and stick it in the web-inf/lib folder so that it can be found on your dev box.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2530

Answer (score 0):

We're [working on this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2531). I expect we'll have a CT4E 1.4.1 release that integrates the above workaround early next week; that is, around 10/31. That should suffice until the underlying issue in the Cloud SDK is fixed.